# The name of a constructor must match the name of the enclosing class

Tags: flutter, dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'D:\Coding\flutter_windows_3.3.10-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'D:\Coding\flutter_windows_3.3.10-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

final Map<String, dynamic> hotel;
const HotelScreen({Key? key, required this.hotel}) : super (key: key);

Comment: can you add the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor name has to be the same as the name of the class.

Is your `HotelScreen` class respect this syntax ?

```
class HotelScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> hotel;
  const HotelScreen({
    Key? key,required this.hotel}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: yah it's the same of this massage